# EF CascadeOnDelete Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this entity:

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    [Required]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And this one:

```
public class Company : PrimaryKey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

How do I use fluent api to enable cascade delete, I tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasOptional<Account>().WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

But I have no idea what this means. Basically, I want a `Company` to have an optional `Account` which will be deleted when the company is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping you need is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasOptional(c => c.Account)
    .WithRequired(a => a.Company)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

It's a one-to-one relationship between `Company` and `Account`. With this mapping you can remove the `[ForeignKey("Company")]` attribute and the `[Required]` attribute anyway because a `Guid` is not nullable and therefore always required.

Comment: Question: if `Company` had an `ICollection<Contacts>` how do you have the associated contacts get deleted when company is deleted? @Slauma

Comment: @No1_Melman: `modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.Contacts).WithOptional(c => c.Company).WillCascadeOnDelete();` If the relationship is required (i.e. `WithRequired(c => c.Company)`) you don't need `WillCascadeOnDelete()` because cascading delete is enabled by default for required one-to-many relationships. If you don't have a `Contact.Company` property in your model use `WithOptional()` (or `WithRequired()`) without lambda parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please folow the link [Enabling Cascade Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete).

> You can configure cascade delete on a relationship by using the
>   WillCascadeOnDelete method. If a foreign key on the dependent entity
>   is not nullable, then Code First sets cascade delete on the
>   relationship. If a foreign key on the dependent entity is nullable,
>   Code First does not set cascade delete on the relationship, and when
>   the principal is deleted the foreign key will be set to null.
>
> You can remove these cascade delete conventions by using:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()
```

> The following code configures the relationship to be required and then
>   disables cascade delete.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Department)
    .WithMany(t => t.Courses)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

something like it in your example:

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Company>()
  .HasOptional<Account>()
  .HasForeignKey(a => a.CompanyId)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: I've read all that you posted and more, and I can't understand what I have to do in relation to my entities.

Comment: Now it just red underlines `HasOptional` which I guess means i need something like `x => x.Account`?? When that is done, it complains there is no `.HasForeignKey`